# Using DAO pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao, dto

I am trying to use the DAO pattern in my multiple web app projects. I have three different web applications and they share two different databases. Each databases have number of tables.

Now I am wondering how I can make my program modular by using best practice. I am thinking of making:

- DAO project which have two factory class for each database, DAO interfaces for each tables and DTO for each tables.
- Then in each web app project I am planning to write implementation code for DAO interface and necessary utility class for getting and closing the connections.

Is this approach good? The doubt/problem i am having is with this design if I am going to ship any one of the project I have to ship DAO project also but that will contain unnecessary info about other databases.

Or will it be good to attach all necessary DAO in web app itself? If so then I have to write same DAO ode for each web app.

Hope anyone can provide me the clear path for this DB connection using DAO pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're headed in the right direction by separating your concerns.

You mention the multiple web apps rely on the two databases. Does each web app rely on both databases? If so, I'd consider creating a single DAO project to encapsulate all the data access logic.

If it's more a mix and match (web app a uses db a, web app b uses db b, web app c uses a and b), I'd consider having two DAO projects, one per database, unless there's a lot of combined logic - that is, when an app uses both databases, it's doing joins between them [yes, I have had projects that do this].

I'd also recommend looking at an Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) framework such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and/or a Dependency Injection framework such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about), which can help simplify the process of separating the various projects and then using them together.

You're clearly planning a pretty ambitious project, so taking advantage of existing frameworks to minimize recreating the wheel will let you focus on your specific problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

- Use JPA to access DB. If not possible then use JdbcTemplate (Spring)
- EntityManager (JPA) is a kind of a DAO
- DAO only where it makes sense (e.g. complex, reusable logic using an EntityManager)
- Use pooled connections/ DataSources
- DTO are usually only needed if your objects need to leave the JVM (e.g. remote EJB services, web services,...)
- use EJBs for container-managed transactions
- consider the Gateway pattern (a stateful session bean and an extended persistence context, see "Real World Java EE Patterns – Rethinking Best Practices" by Adam Bien) and just return the attached entity.